# Parsing "multipart/form-data" in .NET/C#

Tags: c#, .net, html

Got a .NET/C# question...

I need to parse some input post data thats in a "multipart/form-data" format to extract the passed username and password. Anyone know how to do this without writing my own parsing code?

Note the input post data looks something like this:

```
---------1075d313df8d4e1d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

x@y.com
---------1075d313df8d4e1d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

somepassword
---------1075d313df8d4e1d--
```

To demostrate my code looks something like this at the moment:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Login", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
public Stream Login(Stream input)
{
    string username = String.Empty;
    string password = String.Empty;

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(input);
    string strInput = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Dispose();

    // Help needed here:
    usermame = ?.Parse(strINput, "username");
    password = ?.Parse(strINput, "password");

    // blah blah blah return login XML response as a Stream
}
```

Comment: See here for a solution that does not require ASP.NET: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460088/reading-file-input-from-a-multipart-form-data-post/21689347#21689347

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Marc's got it. The easiest way to use the ASP.NET compatibility requirements mode is to apply the [AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.aspnetcompatibilityrequirementsmode.aspx) attribute on your operation. Then you have access to the [HttpContext form params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params%28VS.71%29.aspx). Here's how you'd go about it:

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
                    UriTemplate = "Login", 
                    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = 
                    AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
        public Stream Login(Stream input)
        {
            string username = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["username"];
            string password = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["password"];
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did manage to get AspNetCompatibility mode working so this is a feasible solution. However this wouldn't work with my unit tests as I spin up an instance of my service in code and you can't set the AspNetCompatibility mode in code (as far as I know), see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721219
So in the end I've just written a custom parser using RegEx. Not what I originally wanted to do as its not the most elegent solution but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 2):

Could you not post to a regular ASP.NET page (perhaps an ashx/handler, or MVC) and just use `Request.Form`? This supports multi-part.

Comment: No, this is for a RESTful service, so ASPX/ASHX/MVC aren't a possibility.

Comment: In which case, would ASP.NET compatibility mode be an option, and use HttpContext.Current.Request?