# How to programatically create a WCF service and its metadata on the same URL

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

**TL;DR**
I would to run all three things("You have created a web service" page, WSDL page and actual web service) on the same URL, similarly to a WCF service project created in a standalone WebService application.

I am working on creating WCF endpoints programatically and got most of it together. The last thing is that I can't get the metadata URL to be the same as the service URL. I know this should be possible as you can create services like that from Visual Studio.

What happens is I can browse WSDL in the browser, I can add it as a web reference but I can't invoke it from the newly created project. If I remove both friendly page and wsdl pages, i can invoke the service.

Below is the code that I am using.

```
class Program
{
    private static ManualResetEvent _ResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;

        var serviceUrl = "Fibonacci.svc";
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            var baseUri = new Uri("http://ws.test.com");
            var serviceUri = new Uri(baseUri, serviceUrl);
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Fibonacci), new[] { baseUri }))
            {
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true, HttpGetUrl = new Uri(baseUri, serviceUrl) });
                host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>().IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
                host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>().HttpHelpPageUrl = serviceUri;

                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFibonacci), binding, serviceUri);

                Console.WriteLine("Started service on cotnract {0}, ready for anything", typeof(IFibonacci).FullName);

                host.Open();
                _ResetEvent.WaitOne();
            }
        }).Start();



        while (true)
        {
            var cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.C && (cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0)
            {
                _ResetEvent.Set();
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out the solution is simple. The [documentation for HttpGetUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicemetadatabehavior.httpgetenabled.aspx) is slightly obtuse, basically in order to get all three to work off the same URL you need to create the `ServiceHost` with the **full URL** of the service and then only set `ServiceMetaBaseBehaviour.HttpGetEnable` to `true`.

Relevant code is below.

```
var baseUri = new Uri("http://ws.test.com");
var serviceUri = new Uri(baseUri, serviceUrl);
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Fibonacci), serviceUri /*Specify full URL here*/))
{
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true /*Do not specify URL at all*/});
    host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>().IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
    host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>().HttpHelpPageUrl = serviceUri;

    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IFibonacci), binding, string.Empty /*Url here can either be empty or the same one as serviceUri*/);

    Console.WriteLine("Started service on cotnract {0}, ready for anything", typeof(IFibonacci).FullName);

    host.Open();
    _ResetEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of [article in InfoWorld](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3034606/application-development/how-to-work-with-a-wcf-service-programmatically.html), see 4th line for alternative, cleaner method to specify mex endpoint that avoids any URL issues mentioned above. This is useful when service exposes endpoints using other bindings (eg netTcp):

```
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(New ServiceMetadataBehavior() With {.HttpGetEnabled = True})
        host.Description.Behaviors.Find(Of ServiceDebugBehavior)().IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = True
        host.Description.Behaviors.Find(Of ServiceDebugBehavior)().HttpHelpPageUrl = serviceUri

        host.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(IMetadataExchange), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex")
```

(with apologies to those allergic to VB)