# Programmatically creating WCF service application

Tags: .net, wcf

How to programatically create a empty(sample) WCF application using console application.

I have some idea we can do this using the below:

```
System.Type t = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.9.0");
object obj    = Activator.CreateInstance(t, true);
```

But, I need some more details on this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907791/how-to-programatically-create-a-wcf-service-and-its-metadata-on-the-same-url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programatically create a WCF service and its metadata on the same URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907791/how-to-programatically-create-a-wcf-service-and-its-metadata-on-the-same-url)

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from one of my UnitTests

```
            var binding = new HttpBinding();
            var serviceAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/someservicepath")
            var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService), serviceAddress));
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITestService), binding, serviceAddress);
            host.Open();
            //do stuff
            host.Close();
            host.Dispose();
```

Comment: Hi Aron, I have to create a  WCF service application