# <serviceHostingEnvironment> through C# code in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

How do I set serviceHostingEnvironment=true through c# code?
It seems to be readonly.

Please advice..
Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which property of ServiceHostingEnvironment do you want to set?

The class itself is marked as public static, so you can't "set" it, only use the properties it exposes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehostingenvironment.aspx

Possible duplicate of this question:
[How to set ServiceHostingEnvironment.AspNetCompatibilityEnabled = true in Code (not in config) .NET/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721219/how-to-set-servicehostingenvironment-aspnetcompatibilityenabled-true-in-code-n)

Answer (score 0):

`<serviceHostingEnvironment>` is not a property, it's a tag containing properties.  You need to set the relevant property instead, i.e., [`ServiceHostingEnvironment.ASPNetCompatibilityEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehostingenvironment.aspnetcompatibilityenabled.aspx).